# Are "swipe" and "fling" the same in iOS

Tags: android, ios, uiswipegesturerecognizer, onfling

I am very new to iOS, in Android developing, I understand the fling gesture, but I cannot find the fling in iOS but find swipe gesture, if I want to implement fling up and down, I need to add two UiSwipeGestureRecognizers and set the direction as down and up, am I right? My second question is how to execute swipe gesture in iOS simulator, I always trigger pan gesture not swipe one.

Comment: You can trigger swipe gesture in simulator by press and hold left click and then swipe up or down.

but if you use pan gesture and swipe gesture on same view then swipe gesture will not work easily.

Comment: Your first question is right.

Comment: So what should I do if I want to use pan and swipe gesture in the same view, are there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question, question1, yes, I should add two recognizers. The second is how to `requireGestureRecognizerToFail` to tell the detector that when A action fails trigger Action B.